# explicit formula for calculation of coefficients in piecewise polynomial representation of uniform cardinal B-spline

Tags: polynomials, spline

I want to compute the monomial coefficients of a uniform cardinal B-spline of order d explicitly.
Can someone point me to a useful source? I found many sources for evaluation of B-Splines and I know of the corresponding functions in MATLAB calculating the ppform. What I am interested is the algorithm behind this functions.

Comment: You can find basic knowledge and algorithms on this book(Chapter 5 and Chapter 6).Don't worry, the book is thin. https://geom.ivd.kit.edu/downloads/pubs/pub-boehm-prautzsch_2002_preview.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I already looked at many sources. Unforrunately I wasn‘t able to find an explicit formula for the polynomial coefficients nor a good starting point for the calculation. Perhaps you can provide me some more hint.

Comment: The Matlab algorithms come from Carl de Boor's book "A Practical Guide to Splines", which contains all the theory.